# Mathematical chessboard question complex

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, chessboard

Consider an odd chessboard with an odd number of squares. A king is placed on each square of the board, then the kings are picked up and placed on each square of the board again. Can this be done in a way that every king is in a square next to its original position?

Note: we do not follow the rules of chess in this question, it is practical

Answer (score 5):

No, because every pawn will change the color of the square it stays on, and there is different number of light and dark squares on the odd-sized board.

**Edit**: Adding a new point into the question is a bad practice, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: If the board is even, it is possible to split it into pairs of adjacent squares and just swap the pawns on them, so the answer is positive in this case.

Comment: Prove what?&#8203;